Customer Portal Account on Account object not available for setting filter on Work Order Record Pages
I have setup a lookup relationship from WorkOrder to Account. I am trying to hide a component on the workorder record page based on the value of the Customer Portal Account value of the related account record. I do have the permission to this field but on the filter I am not able to see this field at all.
What could be wrong?
Thanks
